# MetaMask not picking Hardhat Accounts from Port 8545

Tags: metamask, hardhat

I have hardhat node running on http://127.0.0.1:8545/. However, On MetaMask (in FireFox), when I select Localhost:8545 as a Test Network, the first Account is entirely different from the List of 20 Accounts I see on Hardhat.

Could someone help me here.

Kind Regards

Singham

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you are starting a node locally hardhat will give you 10 accounts along with their private keys (iirc they will always be the same).

In order for any of those accounts to be visible on Metamask you will need to manually import any of these accounts by adding their private key, as described in their [docs](https://metamask.zendesk.com/hc/en-us/articles/360015489331-How-to-import-an-Account).

Those imported accounts wont be associated with the seed phrase of your Metamask account in any way though.

Comment: Many thanks my friend. It works like a charm!!